# How to get first resolved recursive promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a project I made for fun: https://github.com/djcaesar9114/actor-connection/
The goal is to check the connections between actors, depending on the movies they played in.
For example:

- Jim Carrey and Renée Zellweger are connected through 1 movie (Me, Myself and Irene);
- Jim Carrey and Hugh Grant are connected through 2 movies (you get from Jim Carrey to Renée Zellweger with "My, Myself and Irene" and from Renée Zellweger to Hugh Grant with "Bridget Jones", because Jim Carrey and Hugh Grant have never played together).

I explain my code (check the README before):

- I have a promise to get the actors of a movie;
- I have a promise to get the movies of an actor;
- I have a recursive promise (arguments: first actor, final actor, path, parameters) that does the following:

> - check all the movies from the actor
> - for each movie, check all the actors of the movie
> - if one actor is the final actor we're looking for, resolve
> - if not, for each actor launch the recursive promise (arguments: current actor, final actor, path combined with the current actor and the movie, parameters)

When a path has been found, the server returns it to the client (and all the other promises are stopped thanks to a global variable changed to `true` wheh it occurs). There is no problem with the client.

The problem is that even though the server finds a path (I see that on the log), it seems it doesn't resolve the promise.

If anybody could help me, it would allow me to understand more the mechanisms of the promises, although before posting here I spent a lot of time looking through the documentation, and all the stackoverflow publications containing "recursive promises".

Feel free to ask any question if I'm not clear enough.

Thanks.

PS: if you want to check my "Carrey / Grant" example, it's faster if you use these parameters:

[image: parameters for the example]

Comment: Does each recurse of your promise rely on data from that previously resolved promise, or is your recursive process simply the creation of them all (with you running them afterwards)

Comment: Each recurse rely on data previously resolved. It's like a tree of promises, if you want, and the algorithm stops to search the branches when it finds a leaf.

Comment: In that case, I highly suggest you do not take a recursive approach. While it depends on the context behind your implementation needs, turning the operation into a queue of promises is going to be a _lot_ easier. Recursion is hard to prematurely stop. A queue is iterative, so it is easy to break out of. You are essentially implementing DFS (depth first search). I am recommending a BFS (breadth first)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check how to modify my algorithm to get rid of the recursion-based search.